# Выберите вариант: чтобы или что бы?

Tags: грамматика, союзы, бы

Как правильно выбрать и объяснить **форму** написания. **Какие** это предложения?

**Разговор о нем**

(1) *Не знаю, **что()бы** он сказал.*

(2) *Сомневаюсь, **что()бы** он это сказал.*

(3) ***Что()бы** н(?) сказал, какая разница.*

(4) *А **что()бы** ему это не сказать.*

(5) ***Что()бы** н(?) сказать, нужно не знать.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Не знаю, что бы он сказал.

(2) Сомневаюсь, чтобы он это сказал.

(3) Что бы ни сказал, какая разница.

(4) А что бы ему это не сказать?

(5) Чтобы не сказать, нужно не знать.

Объяснять - это длинно: оно ж всё очевидно. О_о

Comment: Спасибо! С одним вариантом не согласна.

Comment: В 5-м должно быть слитно.

Comment: Саша, спасибо! Прозевала! Зациклилась на не/ни.

Comment: Спасибо!! Вы такие умные! Надо будет вам что-нибудь потруднее придумать,

Comment: А рискни! Только правил не проси!!!

Comment: Так тоже завтра когда-нибудь. Придумать же надо. Я сколько старалась, а вы так быстро разгадали.  Ладно, пусть будет у нас игра без правил.

Comment: Давай, Шаронушка, придумывай! Без пугающих слов ***Как правильно выбрать и объяснить форму написания. Какие это предложения?***

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что он сказал бы. Не знаю, чтобы он сказал?

Сомневаюсь, что он сказал бы? Сомневаюсь, чтобы он сказал.

Что ни сказал бы, какая разница. Чтобы не сказал, какая разница?

А что ему это не сказать бы? А чтобы ему этого не сказать.

Чтобы не сказать, нужно не знать. Что ни сказать бы - нужно не знать!

Comment: Смотрю сейчас на ваши ответы (я их и не видела!) и не очень понимаю их. Решения здесь, как мне думается, должны быть однозначные. Например: Не знаю, чтобы он сказал?  Это неверно. Защищайтесь, сэр))  Только уж завтра.

Comment: @Sharon да я сам не понял, еще подумаю), в общем как идея, что *что бы* можно разбить словами - *что такое бы* или перемещать бы в конец. А *чтобы* можно совсем выкинуть: не знаю, он сказал? ~ не знаю, чтобы он сказал? И кроме того, мне кажется, есть чередование вопрос-утверждение.

Comment: Нет, там просто отдельные реплики, они не связаны между собой. Построены строго по грамматике: листала учебник и выбирала походящие темы. А наши умники (в хорошем смысле)  их в момент "расщелкали", без учебников и правил. Вот почему? Четыре первых варианта стандартные, а пятый я сама придумала. Он-то и оказался труднее других.

Comment: @Sharon да я тут причем, я все у Галины сдул.

Comment: Как это при чем?) Вы же написали ответ, да еще свое добавили. Мне кажется, не очень удачно.